# Porque me da el error : expected an indent block

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random

random = ["Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5"]

for item in range(1,5):

chosen=(random.choice(random))

main_var.remove(chosen)

print(chosen)
```

Comment: Porque tras los dos puntos que hay en un `if` o `for`, la siguiente línea debe ir indentada. O quizás las siguientes líneas si el bloque de código condicional o a repetir ocupa varias líneas. Eso sin contar con que el código que has pegado no tiene el formato apropiado para StackOverflow (mira aqui --> https://bit.ly/SOesPASTE como pegarlo bien), y por tanto no está muy claro si los errores de indentación ya estaban en tu código original (parece que sí) o han sido el resultado de pegarlo "mal" aqui.

Comment: Uri, tengo un par de dudas. 1.- ¿De dónde sale la variable **main_var**? 2.- ¿El **random** dentro del choice, corresponde a la variable de tipo lista, verdad? De ser así, y para aumentar la claridad, deberías evitar usar palabras reservadas como nombres de variables y/o funciones.

Answer (score 1):

Uri, el error: expected an indent block es debido a que Python es un lenguaje donde la identación es necesaria, esto indica al compilador en donde comienza un nuevo bloque de código, es algo equivalente a los corchetes en otros leguajes {}.

En el caso de un ciclo iterativo como el for, todas las acciones que se deben ejecutar dentro de este debe indicase identandolas, puede hacerse con la tecla TAB o dejando espacios (generalmente 4).

Para tu caso puede ser así:

```
for item in range(1,5):
    chosen=(random.choice(random))
    main_var.remove(chosen)
    print(chosen)
```

Sin embargo tendras otro error debido a que en importas la libreria random y posteriormente creas una variable llamada random asignado una lista, además de esto se está invocando una variable main_var que no es declarada, tambien te dará otro error.